# When playback video recorded with webcam on Raspberry Pi, video plays really fast

Tags: python, opencv, video, raspberry-pi, fourcc

After recording a video on Raspberry Pi by calling a script from the command line to save that video, once we click on that video it plays like x3 faster than we want. So, if we're trying to record for 7 seconds it plays all those 7 seconds in one second. The script works fine on laptops.

We've tried changing the codec and the fps and the resolution.

I've already looked at similar questions but didn't really understand what they suggested. Something about manually counting frame rates. But then what?

Is it because the Raspberry Pi processor isn't that strong?

Also, what CODEC should we use for a Raspberry Pi B+?

Thank you!

Comment: what's the framerate of your camera? probably your video files uses a higher framerate

Comment: We ended up slowing down the fps to 8fps and it works okay now, but still a bit laggy